# Order By double number causes Error 3035

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have inherited an Access database that was built in Access 2007. There is a specific table with 147 columns and over 63K of records. When I try order the table by a specific double number field (with at least 14 decimal places), I receive an error 'System Resources Exceeded' (Error# 3035).

Is there any solutions to this issue? (Change the field to a Short Text or something?)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be thorough, is your database linked to any other databases? I know I have gotten this error when doing complex linking to other databases.

Comment: No. This is one single database.

Comment: If it's necessary to be able to sort by this column, you can try to create an **index** on the column (allow duplicates).

Comment: Can you check what KB hotfixes you have installed?  "
    KB2553447 is a security hotfix which, as an unexpected side effect, causes some queries to give the "System resources exceeded" error.
    KB2760394, referenced by the link Chris posted, is a *different* hotfix, the purpose of which is to fix the problem caused by KB2553447."  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/eda4991f-ac30-4e98-87ba-8d528ae7cfde/system-resources-exceeded-ms-access-2010

Comment: Unfortunately, indexing the column did not work. I still received the 3035 error. I also do not have KB2553447 installed on my computer.

Comment: Could you post some SQL code and the database schema? Maybe you should think about split the table on many tables... 147 columns for a table is a HUGE number of columns...

Comment: If you create a new SELECT query like `SELECT DoubleField, some_other_fields FROM yourTable ORDER BY DoubleField`, does the same error come up when you open it?

Comment: Just because you, the close-voter, don't understand the question, that's not a reason for closing the question; just leave it.

Comment: Did you run a repair and compact of the database? Do make a backup first.

Comment: you could try increasing the maxLocksPerFile. You can do this temporarily in VBA

Comment: maxLocksPerFile was never the solution/issue. I tried it the second I noticed the error, both in the registry on my local computer and in the temp maxLocksPerFile already present in the VBA. Repair and compact doesn't do anything to resolve the issue either.I can't post the code or database schema for specific reasons (unfortunately). I'm currently working on splitting the database in order to isolate the massive table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who provided a suggestion. I was able to stop the error from occurring when I isolated the large table into it's own database. I'm still unsure as to why the error occurs, but at least there's something done for now. Thank you again.